# $\mathbb{R}$ action on a manifold $M$ induced by a vector field $X$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Suppose we have a manifold $M$ and non-vanishing vector field $X$ on it. That vector firld induces a flow $\phi^X$. If the domain of $\phi^X$ is $\mathbb{R} \times X$ than we have an action of $\mathbb{R}$ on $M$. But what happens if the flow is not global (domain is not whole $\mathbb{R} \times M$), is there any natural way to define $\mathbb{R}$ action on M than?

Comment: What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: I think I have written what is my problem. Are integral curves of every non vanishing vector field orbits of $\mathbb{R}$ action (with that field being image of generator of lie algebra of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You can have vector fields that vanish and the still induce actions of all of $\mathbb R$, consider eg on $M=\mathbb R$ the vector field $x\partial_x$, the integral curves are $\phi_t(x)= x e^{ t }$, which are globally defined. And not every vector field that doesn't vanish induces globally defined integral curves, consider something like $(1+x^2) \partial_x$, where the integral curves are $\phi_t(x) = \tan(\arctan(x)+t)$ which cannot be extended globally.

Comment: I know that the integral curves aren't than defined for all times, yet are they perhaps orbits of some $\mathbb{R}$ action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, given any smooth vector field $X$ on $M$, there is an $\mathbb R$-action whose orbits are exactly the integral curves of $X$ (but with different parametrizations, of course).

Let $X\in \mathfrak X(M)$ be a smooth vector field, and let $f\colon M\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth positive exhaustion function.  (To say that $f$ is an ***exhaustion function*** means that $f^{-1}(-\infty,c]$ is compact for every $c\in \mathbb R$. Such a function always exists; see, for example, Prop. 2.28 in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, 2nd ed.) The function $\phi\colon M\to \mathbb R$ given by $\phi(x) = \min(1,1/|Xf(x)|)$ is positive and continuous on $M$, so by the Whitney approximation theorem there is a smooth function $\psi\colon M\to\mathbb R$ such that $0<\psi(x)<\phi(x)$ for all $x\in M$. If we let $\widetilde X = \psi X$, then $|\widetilde X f|\le 1$ everywhere, which implies that $|f(\gamma(t))| \le c_0 + |t|$ along every integral curve $\gamma$ of $\widetilde X$. If $\widetilde X$ were not complete, there would be a maximal integral curve that is not defined for all time, but whose image stays in a compact set $f^{-1}(-\infty,b]$; but the escape lemma (Lemma 9.19 in my book) shows that this cannot happen. Thus $\widetilde X$ is complete, and its flow is an $\mathbb R$-action.

Comment: You would like to have $\phi(x)=min(1,1/|X_x|f(x))$? I find your answear very helpful.

Comment: @J.E.M.S: No, not quite. The expression $|X_x|$ doesn't have any meaning unless we choose a Riemannian metric on $M$. Instead, I was referring to the value at $x$ of the real-valued function $Xf$, which is defined by $Xf(x) = X_x f$.

Comment: All right, I see I misunderstood what is going on and have to rethink your construction.

Comment: @J.E.M.S: I just realized I left out absolute value signs in my definition of $\phi$; fixed now. No wonder you misunderstood. :-(